# How to calculate top rows from a large data set

Tags: r, aggregate, subset

I have a dataset in which there are following columns: flavor, flavorid and unitSoled.

```
Flavor Flavorid unitsoled
beans  350       6
creamy 460       2
.
.
.
```

I want to find top ten flavors and then calculate market share for each flavor. My logic is market share for each flavor = units soled for particular flavor divided by total units soled.

How do I implement this. For output I just want two col Flavorid and corresponding market share. Do I need to save top ten flavors in some table first?

Comment: aggregate(unitsoled ~ Flavorid, df, sum) -> this part is working sum of units soles by id after this I want to display top 10 flavors and then calculate market share for each of these top 10 flavors using formula: units soled for particular flavor divided by total units soled. head(df2, 10)->> this is not displaying the right result.

Comment: Take a look at Lyzander's detailed answer

Answer (score 4):

One way is with the `dplyr` package:

An example data set:

```
flavor    <- rep(letters[1:15],each=5)
flavorid  <- rep(1:15,each=5)
unitsold  <- 1:75
df <- data.frame(flavor,flavorid,unitsold)

> df
   flavor flavorid unitsold
1       a        1        1
2       a        1        2
3       a        1        3
4       a        1        4
5       a        1        5
6       b        2        6
7       b        2        7
8       b        2        8
9       b        2        9
...
...
```

**Solution:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(flavorid,unitsold) %>%             #select the columns you want
  group_by(flavorid) %>%                    #group by flavorid
  summarise(total=sum(unitsold)) %>%        #sum the total units sold per id
  mutate(marketshare=total/sum(total)) %>%  #calculate the market share per id
  arrange( desc(marketshare)) %>%           #order by marketshare descending
  head(10)                                  #pick the 10 first
  #and you can add another select(flavorid,marketshare) if you only want those two
```

**Output:**

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

   flavorid total marketshare
1        15   365  0.12807018
2        14   340  0.11929825
3        13   315  0.11052632
4        12   290  0.10175439
5        11   265  0.09298246
6        10   240  0.08421053
7         9   215  0.07543860
8         8   190  0.06666667
9         7   165  0.05789474
10        6   140  0.04912281
```

Comment: You don't need to calculate the allmarket ahead of time, it can be done in the mutate call as `mutate(marketshare = total/sum(total) ` .  The head line can also be `head(10)`  - no need for the dot.

Comment: @JesseRaab Thanks for your comment Jesse. Both are valid points. I made the changes.

Comment: thanks guys. I am a newbie so want to know what is %>% here in solution ?

Comment: It is called pipe and it comes from the `magrittr` package. It is also used in the dplyr `package` above. It sends the left hand side of `%>%` to the right hand side of it. For example `df  %>% select(flavorid,unitsold)` sends the data.frame `df` to the function `select` which selects columns flavorid and untisold. I suggest you take a look at the introduction to dplyr [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). It is very easy to follow and explains all the functions above. And it is short.

Comment: I have one more basic question:

Comment: How to add a new column to an dataset. This new column will have 1 in all the cells.

Comment: `%>% mutate(name_of_the_column=1)` will do the job.